# Adding Subview creates layout issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm programmatically adding a view inside another view like so:

```
func addViewControllerToSpecificView( view: UIView, controller: UIViewController) {
        controller.willMoveToParentViewController(self)
        view.addSubview(controller.view)           
        self.addChildViewController(controller)
        controller.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }
```

The issue is that the parent view ends up being wider than it should be (the width of the screen).

When I don't load the subview using the above method, the positioning is perfect (no extra padding). I have no idea why it's adding an extra ~30px

[image]

Comment: You need to add autolayout constraints.

Comment: Please add subview frame size code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add following line in your code....

```
controller.view.frame = self.view.layer.bounds;
```

this will fix the problem.

Comment: I'm agree with @nhgrif, You have to use Auto layout.

Comment: Worked! I just changed the `self.view.layer.bounds` to the dedicated view it's being added to, so `view.layer.bounds`, and working like a charm! Thanks.

Comment: What's the difference between auto-layout and this?

Comment: @denislexic: This is matter of choice, but at the end you'll realise "Autolayout" is  that how useful and great feature!

Comment: It's not a matter of choice.  What happens when your parent view's size changes?  Say, for example, when your app is launched on a new iPad Pro in split screen mode.

Comment: Good point @nhgrif . How would I go about adding auto layout in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know that are you adding Auto layout constraint for this view.

Please check that this layout constraints are added in your code, if not then add below constraint after you add `childViewController`.

```
let metrices = ["width" : view.bounds.size.width, "height" : view.bounds.size.height]

view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[childView(width)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: metrices, views: ["childView" : controller.view]))

view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[childView(height)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: metrices, views: ["childView" : controller.view]))
```

Comment: No... these autolayout constraints probably don't do anything different.  He almost certainly needs to add autolayout constraints between the child view controller's view and the parent view he's adding it to...

Comment: @nhgrif Yes, He has to check by implementing required constraints for adding view. Answer is general guidelines to add view with constraints using VFL (Visual Formatting language), probably he'll use it in a way.